# Displaying objects grouped by date - getting an array of hashes when I need an object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, group-by, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am attempting to collect all records of `Product`, grouped by updated_at, then render a partial view with a table for each date.

The problem is I am getting an array of hashes instead of a list of objects when I am in my partial.

My Controller:

```
@products = Product.all.group_by { |product| product.updated_at.to_date}
```

My View `index.html.erb`:

```
<% @products.each do|products_for_one_day| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'product_table', :locals => { :products => products_for_one_day } %>
<% end %>
```

My Partial `_product_table.html.erb`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>example</th>
  </tr>

  <% products.each do |product| %> 
    <tr>
      <td><%= product.example %></td>
      . . .
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

When I get to this view, my `products` variable contains an array where the first object is the date, then the second object is my list of products:

```
[Sun, 16 Dec 2012, [#<Product id: 184, example: "FirstItem"> #<Product id: 191, name: "SecondItem">]]
```

. . .  So my first `product` is simply the date, and I cannot render a table based on a date, then the second product is a hash containing my (in this example, 2) products which I can't iterate over in the way I want anyway because they are not Product objects (that I can call product.example on).

How do I correct this so that I can build a table with the Product objects at this point instead of having to deal with this odd array hash object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating like this:

```
<% @products.each do|date, products_for_one_day| %>
  <% render :partial => 'product_table', :locals => { :products => products_for_one_day } %>
<% end %>
```